# Cursor is Null in Service Class - But Returns Value in Standalone Activity Class

Tags: java, android, service, nullpointerexception, alarmmanager

My classmates and I are stuck on an issue with android application we are building.

We've successfully built an Android app which contains an activity which searches our browser histories / bookmarks for specific urls and launches another activity (successfully) if a match is found as an example of an adult content warning implementation.

This is functioning fine.

Now we are implementing a service class to continually execute every few seconds - in order to execute the search of our recent history using our new service class - but we're experiencing a few issues.

Our problem is when we attempt to add the "Nanny" source code from Nanny.java to the service class so the "Nanny" script will search the history continuously, instead of just once - the "Nanny" application continually force closes - due to a null pointer exception at the initialization of our cursor: `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {`

Which is a bit strange because the NullPointerException does not occur when the exact same script is executed outside the service class in a test file we have (Main.java)

Our working Main.java and our working service class [which successfully displays a toast every few seconds] as well as our [failed] combination of the two - are shown below:

Empty Service Class:

```
public class Service_class extends Service {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

Working Nanny.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Nanny extends Activity {

    String Dirty1 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty2 = "www.penthouse.com";
    String Dirty3 = "www.pornhub.com";
    String Dirty4 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty5 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty6 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty7 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty8 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty9 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty10 = "www.playboy.com";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.nanny);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
        projection, null, null, null);
String urls = "";
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
String url1 = null;
String url2 = null;
do {
String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));

if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)) {
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10)) {
//if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Filthy)) {
urls = urls
+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE)) + " : "
+ url + "\n";
Intent intent = new Intent(Nanny.this, Warning.class);
Nanny.this.startActivity(intent);
}
} while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
tv.setText(urls);
}}}
```

Unsuccessful method we've attempted to implement (adding the functioning nanny script to the service class) which causes the NullPointerException: if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

```
public class Service_class extends Service {
    String Dirty1 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty2 = "www.penthouse.com";
    String Dirty3 = "www.pornhub.com";
    String Dirty4 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty5 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty6 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty7 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty8 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty9 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty10 = "www.playboy.com";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //setContentView(R.layout.main3);
      //  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
        Cursor  cursor = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        String urls = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String url1 = null;
        String url2 = null;
        do {
        String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));

        if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10)) {
        urls = urls
        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE)) + " : "
        + url + "\n";
        Intent warning_intent = new Intent(Service_class.this, Warning.class);
        Service_class.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
      //  tv.setText(urls);




        return START_STICKY;

        }
        return startId;}
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
    private void setContentView(int main3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private TextView findViewById(int hello) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Cursor managedQuery(Uri bookmarksUri, String[] projection,
            Object object, Object object2, Object object3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }}
```

LOGCAT (When using combined implementation shown above)

Fails on Line 53:   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

```
04-15 18:26:24.761: D/dalvikvm(7466): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-15 18:26:25.651: D/dalvikvm(7466): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 4% free 7379K/7608K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
04-15 18:26:25.651: I/dalvikvm-heap(7466): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.861MB for 3686416-byte allocation
04-15 18:26:25.661: D/dalvikvm(7466): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 10977K/11212K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
04-15 18:26:25.681: D/dalvikvm(7466): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10977K/11212K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 17ms
04-15 18:26:25.901: D/dalvikvm(7466): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10977K/11212K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
04-15 18:26:25.911: I/dalvikvm-heap(7466): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.086MB for 6529744-byte allocation
04-15 18:26:25.931: D/dalvikvm(7466): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 17354K/17592K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
04-15 18:26:25.941: D/dalvikvm(7466): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 17354K/17592K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 16ms
04-15 18:26:26.051: D/libEGL(7466): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
04-15 18:26:26.061: D/libEGL(7466): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-15 18:26:26.071: D/libEGL(7466): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
04-15 18:26:26.091: D/OpenGLRenderer(7466): Enabling debug mode 0
04-15 18:26:31.181: D/AndroidRuntime(7466): Shutting down VM
04-15 18:26:31.181: W/dalvikvm(7466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f4f930)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.ut.appdemo.Service_class@41698e90 with Intent { cmp=com.ut.appdemo/.Service_class }: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2673)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at com.ut.appdemo.Service_class.onStartCommand(Service_class.java:53)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
04-15 18:26:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7466):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat as well.

Comment: @UTTechLabStudents `tv.setText(urls);` should result in an `NPE` (The non-service `findViewById()` method you made returns `null`). Look into that. Also, Services have no UI, so I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Like A--C says, Services don't run on the UI thread, so you cannot update the UI like this. And tv will always be null because your method findViewById does such. There are some pretty serious conceptual problems in your code.

Comment: We've edited the source code above to comment out any references to the user interface which were leftover from it's standalone implementation without the service class. We are still experiencing a null pointer exception on the following line: if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

Comment: That's because cursor is null ;-)

Comment: Why is it null only in our new service class? The same script is not null in our standalone implementation? What could the difference be?

Comment: We know the cursor is null. We are attempting to determine why.

Comment: [Thanks for the start though!]

Comment: Anyone (else perhaps) have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the cursor to null...

you use this method to instantiate the cursor:

```
Cursor  cursor = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,projection, null, null, null);
```

and then you define managedQuery() method like this:

```
private Cursor managedQuery(Uri bookmarksUri, String[] projection, Object object, Object object2, Object object3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}}
```

essentially what your code says is:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
curser.doSomething();
```

this will always result in a nullPointer. I strongly suggest you go back and study java fundamentals before diving in to android, you are just asking for headaches if you are trying to accomplish something in android with such a lack of understanding of java.

Comment: Apologies - we have a basic grip on Java (we just overlooked that - it was generated by eclipse as a "suggestion" - we didn't actually write that code - thank you for pointing that out though - you just nailed down where our issue stemmed from!)